# Reference point for U tube question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

Referring to the following diagram, I am expected to pick out the one case where the fluid in the tube is not in static equilibrium. They are in the other three cases.
[image]

The answer is that situation 2 is not in static equilibrium. If you use the bottom dashed line as the reference point (any points along a horizontal axis have the same pressure), then in situation 1
$$P_0+\rho_rgh_r=P_0+\rho_ggh_g\tag1$$

where $\rho_r$ is the density of the red fluid, $h_r$ is the length between the top of the red fluid and the bottom dashed line, and likewise for $\rho_g$ and $h_g$ for the grey fluid. Thus,
$$\frac{\rho_r}{\rho_g}=\frac{h_g}{h_r}<1\tag2$$

and $\rho_g>\rho_r$ for the system to be in static equilibrium. This result is all well and good.

However, what if I wanted to use the top of the grey fluid (right side) in situation 1 rather than the bottom dashed line given? In that case, $h_r^\prime=h_r-h_g$ and $h^\prime_g=0$. Plugging this into equation 2,
$$\frac{\rho_r}{\rho_g}=\frac{h^\prime_g}{h^\prime_r}=\frac{0}{h^\prime_r}=0$$
That means that $\rho_r=0$, which shouldn’t be possible, right? I don’t understand how choosing a different reference point influences my result so much. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The reference line has to pass through the same fluid.

Comment: @ChesterMiller What’s the rationale for that?

Comment: If this is the case, then, if you go around the U, the change in pressure from the left point on the reference line to the right point on the reference line is zero.

Comment: @ChesterMiller Isn’t that the point of static equilibrium? No pressure difference = no acceleration of fluid?

Comment: As in any situation, you are checking to see whether the forces are in static equilibrium before addressing any need to consider acceleration.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I think we’ve deviated from my original question. Why does the reference line have to pass through the same fluid? Even if it passes through a different fluid, isn’t the change in pressure *still* zero? Macroscopically, the both fluids don't move (accelerate) and as a whole are in static equilibrium.

Comment: No.  Even it the system is in static equilibrium, if the reference line passes through a different fluid and you calculate the static pressure change from left to right (by first going down the left side of the U and then coming back up the right side of the U), you will find that you calculate a pressure difference between the left side of the reference line and the right side of the reference line.  Try it and see.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine no fluid above the bottom dashed line.  All four situations are in static equilibrium so the pressure along that bottom dashed horizontal line is the same.

Now look at situation 1.
That is a static equilibrium situation if the pressure exerted by each column above the dashed bottom line is the same.

Move the dashed bottom line until it is level with the right hand grey liquid surface.

The pressure at the surface of the grey liquid on the right hand side is atmospheric.
The pressure at the same horizontal level in the red liquid on the left hand side is atmospheric plus the pressure exerted by the column of red liquid above the new position of the dashed horizontal line.
So the pressure in the liquids along that new dashed horizontal line is not the same.

The same analysis can be done for situation 4  but this time raising the bottom dashed horizontal line to the top of the red liquid in the left hand column.

Comment: "The pressure at the same horizontal level in the red liquid on the left hand side is atmospheric plus the pressure exerted by the column of red liquid above the new position of the dashed horizontal line.” That means the pressure on the left side must be higher than the pressure on the right, and there is a pressure change as you go from left to right. That would violate the assumption of static equilibrium, would it not?

Comment: I am trying to show that the pressure along that new dashed horizontal line is not the same ie I was trying to answer you question.

Comment: So where we place the line influences whether the fluid is in static equilibrium?

Comment: No.  Where we place the will determine whether or not we can say the fluid pressure is the same or not.  So in the diagram you can say that the liquid pressure is the same along the lower dashed line or below it but that is not true of a line between the dashed lines.

Comment: But *why* is it not true of a line between the dashed lines?

Comment: Because the goes through liquids of different densities except situation 3 where the liquids must be the same density.

Comment: @lightweaver a difference in pressure does not imply non-equilibrium, because they are two different fluids. If the fluid were the same, then it would need same Pressure, but they are different fluids. $P+\rho gh=const$ applies only to the same fluid.